# Magento 2.2? How to create customer in admin side programmatically?

Tags: customer, magento2.2

I need to create new customer in `admin side` `programmatically`? How to do that in Magento 2?

I have used below coding for creating customer programmatically, I am `getting` new `customerId` but customer is `not saved` in `customer_entity` `table`? why?

```
$websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
               $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();


                $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                        ->setStore($store)
                        ->setFirstname($firstname)
                        ->setLastname($lastname)
                        ->setMobile($mobile)
                        ->setEmail($email)
                        ->setPassword(uniqid());
    $customer->save();
```

After saved new customer, I am getting below error **No such entity with customerId =**